# Save Array Data to datagrid and xml

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which reads data from xml like this:

Xml to Dataset:

```
    public DataSet GetModules()
    {
        DataSet ds = StoreDbDataSet.ReadDataSet();

        ObservableCollection<Module> modules = new ObservableCollection<Module>();
        foreach (DataRow moduleRow in ds.Tables["Modules"].Rows)
        {
            modules.Add(new Module(moduleRow["ModelNumber"].ToString(), moduleRow["ParamName"].ToString(),
                    (UInt16)moduleRow["ParamValue"], (UInt16)moduleRow["DefaultValue"], (UInt16)moduleRow["MaxValue"],
                    (UInt16)moduleRow["MinValue"], (uint)moduleRow["Address"]));
        }
        return StoreDbDataSet.ReadDataSet();
    }
```

Then populate the Dataset to datagrid by this:

```
    private DataSet _ds;
    private void RefreshModules()
    {
        _ds = sdb.GetModules();
        _ds.Tables["Modules"].DefaultView.Sort = "Address";
        ModulesView = new ListCollectionView(_ds.Tables["Modules"].DefaultView)
        {
            Filter = obj =>
            {
                var Module = obj as DataRowView;
                return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelNumber == Module["ModelNumber"].ToString();
            }
        };
    }
```

When I change the value in the datagrid, I save changes to xml like this:

```
    public void SaveDataSet()
    {
        StoreDbDataSet sdb = new StoreDbDataSet();
        sdb.SaveDataSet(_ds);
    }

    public void SaveDataSet(DataSet ds)
    {
        ds.WriteXmlSchema(DatabaseConstructorName);
        ds.WriteXml(DatabaseFileName);
        ds.AcceptChanges();
    }
```

**Problem**: Now I have an Array, I want to save the data in the Array to the datagrid, how should I do?

**Edit:**

```
    public void ArrayToDatagrid()
    {
        StoreDb sdb = new StoreDb();
        var temp = sdb.GetModulesFilteredWithLinq(selectedProduct.ModelNumber).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < dgConfig.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            DataRow newModuleRow = _ds.Tables["Modules"].NewRow();
            newModuleRow["ModelNumber"] = temp[i].ModelNumber;
            newModuleRow["ParamName"] = temp[i].ParamName;
            newModuleRow["ParamValue"] = readRegisters[i];
            newModuleRow["DefaultValue"] = temp[i].DefaultValue;
            newModuleRow["MaxValue"] = temp[i].MaxValue;
            newModuleRow["MinValue"] = temp[i].MinValue;
            newModuleRow["Address"] = temp[i].Address;

            _ds.Tables["Modules"].Rows.Add(newModuleRow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the format of the data you got from the other device? It would also be helpful to know what exactly **Array** means (you have the data in an array format?).

Comment: I got a sampe data like: `ushort[] tempArray = {11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am quite familiar with your code (from previous questions) I'll try to help:

You could add the data directly into your dataset in `RefreshModules()` and then it will get saved into your xml. However, you should find a way to not add duplicates, otherwise it will keep adding the same data again and again.

```
private void RefreshModules()
{
    _ds = sdb.GetModules();
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.Length; i++)
    {
        DataRow newModuleRow = _ds.Tables["Modules"].NewRow();
        newModuleRow[Address] = "your address from other data";
        newModuleRow[ParamValue] = tempArray[i];
        newModuleRow[ParamName] = "your param name";
        ... 
        //use the same syntax to add all the required parameters of a Module structure

        _ds.Tables["Modules"].Rows.Add(newModuleRow);
    }
    _ds.Tables["Modules"].DefaultView.Sort = "Address";
    ModulesView = new ListCollectionView(_ds.Tables["Modules"].DefaultView)
    {
        Filter = obj =>
        {
            var Module = obj as DataRowView;
            return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelNumber == Module["ModelNumber"].ToString();
        }
    };
}
```

If it is a one time addition, you can remove the for loop after running once, otherwise you could put it into a function and call it only when needed.

Alternatively, you could check if the "row" exists in the datatable before adding (e.g. check if paramvalue exists already, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your help again and sorry for my inarticulate words. What I want to do is: I have a datagrid which populate several data from xml file such as `ParamName`,`ParamNumber`,`ParamValue`,`Address`... So when I get the protocol data from other device, I may only get the `ParamValue` corresponds to `Address`, so I may  save the data back to xml not only this two parameters but a full structure of `Module`, hope I make this clear for you!

Comment: I think it is reasonably clear, if you know what to add for the rest of the Module parameters, you can just add more lines after `newModuleRow[ParamValue] = tempArray[i];`, e.g. `newModuleRow[ParamNumber] = "something"` and ``newModuleRow[ParamName] = "something else";``, etc.

Comment: The above **Edit** code works out with creating another table Module, so when I `RefreshModules()` there populates two rows of data for each, I thinks this is because `_ds.Tables["Modules"].Rows.Add(newModuleRow);`do you know how to fix this to modify the existed table instead of creating a new one?Thanks!